# Nominal and Adjectival

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> 1. The fact **that you are here** is an indication of your good intentions

My analysis of the clause in bold is Noun-clause/Adjectival/Post-nominal modifier.
However, my teacher's answer is slightly different. He said that the clause in bold is Noun-clause/**Nominal**/Post-nominal modifier

> 2. The dress **that Melissa is wearing** was designed in Paris.

However, in the sentence above, my teacher said that the clause in bold is Noun-clause/**Adjectival**/Post-nominal modifier

My questions are: 
What is the difference between the Noun-clause in the first sentence and the second sentence? 
Both of them modify the preceding noun, so what makes the first one "Nominal"?

Comment: "That you are here" is a declarative content clause functioning as **complement** of "fact". Some people call it a noun clause, but that is a misnomer. "That Melissa is wearing" is a relative clause **modifying** "dress". Content clauses function as complements while relative clauses function as modifiers.

Comment: @BillJ is right.

Answer (score 2):

As per the **[Towson University Online Writing Support](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/AdvAdjNomClause.htm)**,

In sentence 1 of the OP, the clause in bold is a *Nominal Clause* as appositive of **fact**, and **that** acts here as an expletive. A similar example sentence is here:

> [*The fact **that you are here** is reassuring to me.*](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/AdvAdjNomClause.htm)

In sentence 2, the bold part is an *adjectival clause* describing the subject, **The dress**.

A similar example sentence:

> *[A politician **who is trustworthy** has the support of the people.](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/AdvAdjNomClause.htm)*